# Nagios - Only Want Alert if Service Failed for 15 minutes

Tags: nagios

I read through the documentation and thought my services would alert me 15 minutes after going critical, but I am getting the emails right away.

**/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg**

```
command_check_interval=1
interval_length=60
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/contacts.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/timeperiods.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/templates.cfg
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios/myconfig
```

**/etc/nagios/myconfig/site/services.cfg**

```
define service {
    host_name realhost01
    service_description Disk
    servicegroups DISK
    check_command check_nrpe!check_disk
    use generic-service
    notification_interval 0
}
```

**/etc/nagios/objects/templates.cfg**

```
define service{
        name                            generic-service         
        active_checks_enabled           1                       
        passive_checks_enabled          1                       
        parallelize_check               1                       
        obsess_over_service             1                       
        check_freshness                 0                       
        notifications_enabled           1                       
        event_handler_enabled           1                       
        flap_detection_enabled          1                       
        failure_prediction_enabled      1                       
        process_perf_data               1                       
        retain_status_information       1                       
        retain_nonstatus_information    1                       
        is_volatile                     0                       
        check_period                    24x7                    
        max_check_attempts              3                
        normal_check_interval           5                 
        retry_check_interval            1               
        first_notification_delay        15                     
        contact_groups                  admins                  
        notification_options            u,c,r                   
        notification_interval           0                       
        notification_period             24x7                    
        register                        0
        }
```

Comment: Are you using nagios 3.3.1 or newer? `first_notification_delay` bug was fixed there, apparently.

Comment: nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=27110 says

> The time for "first notification delay" is timed based on the last known OK state

The issue there seems so similar to yours that I expected the same username.  Please check that and see whether it may help?  (no need to award points; this is just a drive-by)